# Java lambda expression for counting unique objects

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have set up this stream below and cant use the method count() on .map. Only on filter. But I havent set up any filter condition. How could I do it on an array of Strings for this stream below?

I want to sort out strings given the regex in replaceAll and get the unique strings and get the number of unique strings total.

```
Stream newStream = Arrays.stream(arr)
                    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""))
                    .distinct()
```

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: @YCF_L Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to count the number of `distinct` strings, you can do it like :

```
long countDistinct = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""))
        .distinct() // intermediate operation with unique strings as 'Stream' return type
        .count();   // terminal operation with count of such strings as return type
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error in Eclipse saying: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to Stream`

Comment: I must use the Stream in declaration.

Comment: @Doerad well you should note the return type of the expression that I've updated, since you needed to account for the 'count' of characters.

Comment: How could I with the 'Stream' as return type, get the of distinct number of String elements? Should I use it in a `newStream.forEach()` and calculate it there?

Comment: @Doerad what's it going to be a stream of? isn't it just one count?

Comment: @Owen No, its an array that I will be counting. `String[] arr = text.split(" ");`

Comment: @Doerad I mean the result. Isn't the result just a number?

Comment: @Owen That is my question how to get it to a number somehow. Right now I get all the results of the strings that matches on each row with this: `newStream.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));`

Comment: The list will also contain a distinct empty String `""`(thereby increasing its count)

Comment: @KrishPrabakar could you explain what you meant? not able to relate

Comment: @Naman After `distinct()` if you print the list, it prints like `[, one, two]`, please notice the empty string as the first element in the list (hence count is `3` not `2`).

Comment: @KrishPrabakar and what was your input? if the array consists of an `""`, then yes there would be 3 distinct elements, note there is no `filter` involved in the question or the answer.

Comment: @Naman - I did this: `String text = "FOO bar BAZ TEXT text some";  String[] arr = text.split(" ");`, this logic is based on OP's comments above.  Without that filter, the list is: `[, bar, some, text]`.  I actually posted my code tried as an answer below.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar I get what you're pointing to, just that the question doesn't seem to be pointing towards that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand your requirement. It seems you want a `List` with the distinct strings sorted after applying the regex to each element of the array. This `List` would have both the elements and their count:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""))
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, `list` holds the elements. And if you want to also know how many elements it contains, simply use the `List.size` method:

```
int count = list.size();
```

---

**EDIT:** If you also need a `Stream` with the strings changed, unique and sorted, simply create a new `Stream` from `list`:

```
Stream<String> newStream = list.stream();
```

Comment: `.filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())` operation is also needed to avoid the empty string - `""` added to the count

Comment: @KrishPrabakar It is not clear from the question if the user wants the empty string or not

Comment: You are right, but (just my thought that) when OP wants the count of unique strings from a text input (say from a file), its most likely that he wanted to avoid such edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Both collecting as a list and getting the total count are terminal operations, hence you can do only *either* on a live stream.

If you must use the ***same*** stream to get **both** the list of strings and count, one (hacky) option would be to use `Supplier<Stream<T>>`:

```
String text = "FOO bar BAZ TEXT text some";
String[] arr = text.split(" ");

Supplier<Stream<String>> sameStream = () -> Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""))
        .distinct()
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .sorted();

System.out.println("Unique strings are: " + sameStream.get().collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println("Count of Unique strings are: " + sameStream.get().count());
```

Above yields this output:

```
Unique strings are: [bar, some, text]
Count of Unique strings are: 3
```